# Azure- Missing Value for AzureWebJobsStorage even though it clearly exists

Tags: python, azure-functions

I have a very basic Azure Blob Trigger function in Visual Studio Code. But for some reason the local.settings.json comes up with the error "Missing value for AzureWebJobsStorage in local.settings.json".

But the value DOES exist. Here is my code:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=****==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
    }
}
```

Obviously the **** is substituted by my actual code. I really don't understand why this isn't working. I'm trying to get a python function to work, my C# functions written in Visual Studio work fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `AzureWebJobsStorage` in this form: `DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<name>;AccountKey=<key>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the missing `AccountKey` is the problem. Value is [supposed to be](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobsstorage) a valid connection string.

> **AzureWebJobsStorage**
>
> The Azure Functions runtime uses this storage account connection string for normal operation. Some uses of this storage account include key management, timer trigger management, and Event Hubs checkpoints. The storage account must be a general-purpose one that supports blobs, queues, and tables. See Storage account and Storage account requirements.
> AzureWebJobsStorage
>
> Key Sample value
>
> AzureWebJobsStorage   DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=[name];AccountKey=[key]